# "TypeError: float argument must be a string or a number, not a list." converting a list of strings to a list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a list of strings into a list of floats.  I have tried list comprehension, mapping, and simply writing it out in a for loop.  I don't really want to use mapping since I can't seem to get it back into a proper list even with `list(map)`.

So far none of my attempts have worked because I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for Python 3x.  My latest attempt seems to show promise, but I keep getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/test.py", line 56, in <module>
heartdis_flt.append(float(item))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

This is the code I am using:

```
heartdis = heartdis[5:]

heartdis_flt = []

for item in heartdis:

    heartdis_flt.append(float(item))

print(heartdis_flt)
```

`heartdis` is a list of strings created from a CSV file.

Can someone explain the correct syntax or maybe some flaw in my logic?

Comment: It means that `heartdis` isn't a `list`, it's a `list` of `list` of *something*.

Comment: I see, so what I need to do is to change the lists to strings first.  Thank you!

Comment: Map will work fine once you actually feed it a list of float strings.  `print(list(map(float, ['1.2', '3', '3.1459'])))` produces `[1.2, 3.0, 3.1459]`.

Answer (score 2):

I found something that will work.  I used itertools to change the list of list into one list then converted it all to floats.

```
    heartdis = heartdis[5:]
    heartdis_flt = []
    heartdis2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(heartdis))
    for item in heartdis2:
        heartdis_flt.append(float(item))
    print(heartdis_flt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @utdemir commented, the problem with your code is that you are treating a list as a string. You indeed could use `itertools.chain`, but maybe you want to change the way you are reading from `heartdis` in the first place. I don't know how you are reading your CSV file, but if you are using the `csv` module, I reckon you should not be getting list of lists as outputs. Anyway, something you should check in my opinion.